# Data structure that sorts elements by value on insert in Python

Tags: python, queue

I need a queue structure that sorts elements (id, value) by value on insert. Also, I need to be able to remove the element with the highest value. I don't need this structure to be thread- safe. In Java, this would, I guess, correspond to PriorirtyQueue.

What structure should I use in Python? Could you provide a single toy example?

Answer (score 7):

Python has [something similar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.PriorityQueue) (which is really a thread-safe wrapper for `heapq`):

```
from Queue import PriorityQueue

q = PriorityQueue()
q.put((-1, 'foo'))
q.put((-3, 'bar'))
q.put((-2, 'baz'))
```

Instead of the largest, you can get the lowest number with `q.get()`:

```
>>> q.get()
(-3, 'bar')
```

If you don't like negatives, you can override the `_get` method:

```
class PositivePriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    def _get(self, heappop=max):
        return heappop(self.queue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) module.

From docs:

> This module provides an implementation of the heap queue algorithm,
>   also known as the **priority queue** algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be found in the heapq library. From http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html :

```
Heap elements can be tuples. This is useful for assigning comparison values (such as task priorities) alongside the main record being tracked:

>>> import heapq
>>>
>>> h = []
>>> heappush(h, (5, 'write code'))
>>> heappush(h, (7, 'release product'))
>>> heappush(h, (1, 'write spec'))
>>> heappush(h, (3, 'create tests'))
>>> heappop(h)
(1, 'write spec')
```

Is this the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[`heapq`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) uses a priority queue, but it's a minimum heap so you will need to make the value negative. Also you will need to put the id second since sorting is done from left to right.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> queue = []
>>> heapq.heappush(queue, (-1, 'a'))
>>> heapq.heappush(queue, (-2, 'a'))
>>> heapq.heappop(queue)
(-2, 'a')
```